# openFiledialog only the name

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

can someone tell me how to only show the name and not the full path in front of the name.
I found this code put in only show the extension or only the filename without the extension. What i want to be shown is the name of the file with the extension.
Like this:
example.txt.

Code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Binary Files (.BIN; .md6; .md7)|*.BIN; *.md6; *.md7|All Files (*.*)|*.*";


        {
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                System.IO.StreamReader sr = new
                System.IO.StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                sr.Close();
            }
        }
        String filedata = openFileDialog1.FileName;

        openFileDialog1.Title = ("Choose a file");
        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:\\Projects\\flashloader2013\\mainapplication\\Bootfiles";

        //textBox1.Text = (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName));
        textBox1.Text = (System.IO.Path.Get(openFileDialog1.FileName));
    }
```

**Thanks all for the help**

Comment: [Path.GetFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx) **Edit** You should include `using System.IO` at the top of your class also, to save you having to keep writing it

Comment: Even though it already has been answered, this is a question which can very easily be found by google or stackoverflow! Use the search next time :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
var onlyfilename = Path.GetFileName(openFileDialog1.FileName);
```

Comment: I will mark it as answer when i can.

Answer (score 4):

have you checked out SafeFileName property?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.safefilename.aspx